# Prove existence and uniqueness of differential/integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

This is a homework question, so I'm essentially asking for hints and not answers due to academic honesty concerns. The course is in real analysis (baby rudin) and it is essentially chapter 9 which should be used to solve this.

The equations are
$$f'=xf(x)+x^2, f(0)=0$$
with solution
$$ f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+c}+ \frac{x^3}{3}-e^c=e^c\left( e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-1\right)+\frac{x^3}{3}.$$

and
$$f(x)=\int_0^x[f(t)+t]\sin(t) dt, f(0)=0$$ 
which at least for continuous $f$ has solution
$$f(x)=e^{-\cos(x)+c}+\sin(x)-x\cos(x)-e^{c}.$$

This is how far I've gotten, but I'm asked to determine uniqueness and explicitly asked to use stuff from CH 9 in Rudin, so I guess something with a contraction/fixed point thm but I can't really figure out what right now.

In the previous part of this exercise we proved that if the jacobian is less than or equal to q, were q<1 its a contraction for a function defined on a convex set. The problem here is that I can't seem to get rid of $e^c$, so I might have not solved it entirely. Suggestions? Or should i assume $c=0$ perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot say how much I want to thank you. **not answers due to academic honesty concerns** we need more people like you here. I will try to do my best in helping.

Comment: That's always nice to hear! I appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For existence and uniqueness you are asked to check the assumptions of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. It is not necessary to repeat the proof of it, which uses the Banach fixed point theorem.

Replace $e^c$ by a multiplicative constant $C$. Which tells that along the way you have missed a sign discussion, or earlier the absolute value signs in $\int\frac1y\,dy=\ln|y|+c$.

The second equation is the Picard iteration form on an ODE that can be obtained by taking the derivative of it. The initial condition there is redundant, since for x=0 the integral automatically has the value 0.

Did you use a modified supremum norm in the proof of Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: Sorry, I should have updated this, my solution to the ODE is way wrong. I showed that they are both contractions (transforming ODE to integral) and thus have unique solutions by the contraction mapping theorem. However, now instead I cant seem to find the solution. Im pretty sure its best expressed as some infinite series so im gonna give that a go, ill upvote for trying to help anyway!

We haven't proven Picard-Lindelöf (well, parts in homeworks and stuff), this is from a real analysis course so im allowed to use it.

Comment: Yes, both equations lead to integrals, $\int e^{\frac{-x^2}2}dx$ and $\int e^{\cos x}dx$, that can not be further simplified. And the question remains: contraction in what norm and on which interval? The first equation has some uncomfortable growth in the coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, contractions in $C[0,1]$ in the supnorm. i.e. define $F: C[0:1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ by
$$F[f]=\int_0^x (f+t)t dt$$
and similarily for the integral equation.

And I agree, the coefficients aren't nice at all, I tried it in mathematica and it its a gauss and and error function for the ODE, I can't seem to arrive at this analytically though.

Comment: Yes, that should work and give contraction factors nicely below $1$. -- The alternative is to consider the Picard iterations on $C(\Bbb R)$, in the case of the first ODE using the modified sup norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}e^{-x^2}|f(x)|$ and in the case of the second the more standard modified sup norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}e^{-2|x|}|f(x)|$ to get contractivity on the whole of $\Bbb R$. In general one uses $e^{-2L\,|x|}$ as modification factor for ODE with Lipschitz constant $L$.